# Move Marker(GPS) to next street

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I have an app Android and I want to set the position(marker) of the user above the street and not in the building or house for example. Like Uber does.

For  example, in this app, the green points are suggeestions to move the marker to street.
[image]

Comment: Please add picture with explanation.

Comment: Add the image to description